# Connect Access Database from c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I’m trying to open Access database.

```
OleDbConnection conn = null;
OleDbDataReader reader = null;


conn = new OleDbConnection(
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
    "Data Source=" + @"C:\test.accdb");
conn.Open();
```

But on conn.Open, I’m getting exception -  Unrecognized database format "C:\test.accdb"

Im’ created this db with Access 2010. So, I’m tried to Access this db using this:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255
But then I’m get exception „Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.”
Now I’m trying this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734 And getting this Unrecognized database format exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
OleDbConnection Con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\test.accdb");
```

Comment: Can you expand this answer to explain why this solution works?

Comment: Does it function to u?

Comment: I don't have the setup necessary to verify correctness. My comment was about the context of the answer. You should explain it so that future visitors to the site will know why this is the right answer.

Comment: I'm assuming the escaped string (with the @) is being added to the un-escaped string, forming one un-escaped string which then errors when the OleDbProvider interprets it.